# Смена обоев через приложение на android

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность написать приложение на Android, которое автоматически меняло обои на смартфоне без помощи пользователя?

Comment: Да. Такая возможность есть. Скажу более - таких приложений в плей маркете очень много.

Comment: И в стандартных функциях оно тоже присудствует.

Comment: копайте в сторону WallpaperManager https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953359/using-wallpapermanager-in-android-to-set-wallpaper